# MongoDB: How to Sort a Query Before Updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm writing a Meteor (Node.js) app which uses MongoDB on the backend. At a certain point in my code, I need to update a *specific* document within a collection. I need to use Mongo's update() method, but I'm having trouble passing in the proper (complex) query to narrow down to that one, specific document. The document I'm trying to update is:

`db.collection.find({market: 'AAA'}).sort({creationDate:-1}).limit(1)`

In words, the one document in `collection` that has a market of `AAA` and was created most recently (creationDate is a UNIX timestamp number, e.g. `1408829429914`). There are multiple documents with a market of `AAA`, so I am using sort() and limit(1) to find the document which was created most recently.

Mongo's [update()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) doesn't seem to accept sorting parameters as part of the query before the update process. What can I do to narrow down to this document and update it? Thanks!

Comment: The only way possible unfortunately, find and then run update, though there is a JIRA for this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1599

Comment: However findandmodify support a sort: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Comment: @Sammaye findAndModify() works perfectly in the Mongo shell! But it is apparently not supported by Meteor.js: `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'findAndModify'`. Any suggestions on how to call this method in javascript?

Comment: I am no meteor expert but it seems this thread holds examples: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1070

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to fetch the document you want and then update it by `_id`. If your collection was called `Markets`, the code would look like:

```
var market = Markets.findOne({market: 'AAA'}, {sort: {creationDate:-1}});
Markets.update(market._id, {$set: {fancy: true}});
```

It's worth mentioning that even if MongoDB supported the optimization you are looking for, meteor client code can only update by `_id` anyway.