# MongoDB updateOne gets the oldest document I want the newest

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Sorry for asking this really basic question but I really want this code to work.

In node.js I update my mongo database successfully using the `.updateOne()` function and I keep the parameters blank as shown below. I thought it would update the most recently added document of the collection however it changes the oldest one.

How can I update the most recently added document in the collection without cycling through the entire collection? Any advice helps and I am open to using another function but would prefer not to.

the "important part":

```js
var collection = db.collection('SensorValues');

collection.updateOne({}, { $set: { "VSWR": 999 } }, function (err, result) {
    console.log("Look I updated something");
});
```

Comment: is there a design  reason why isn't finalID unique?

Comment: I hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/25467237/335905

Answer (score 2):

Just use `db.collection.findOneAndUpdate()` rather than `db.collection.updateOne()` adding the third argument option `returnNewDocument: true`.

> **returnNewDocument** When true, returns the updated document instead of the original document. Defaults to false.

See more at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Comment: In case it helps anyone, the following worked for me - MY CODE BEFORE:  `collection.updateOne(filter, update, function(err, doc) {...`, My CODE AFTER:  `var options = {"returnOriginal": false, "projection": {_id: 0} };  collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options, function(err, doc) {...`

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!! Its pretty easy if you **don't override the _id that mongo provides** each document in a collection. All you have to do is:
 - Keep the filter option blank
 - Set sort to _id:-1

Here is my solution:

```html
var collection = db.collection('SensorValues');//change as needed
  
  //NOTE: {} and sort{_id:-1} both return the newest document 
  collection.findOneAndUpdate(
      {},
      {$set:{"VSWR":0,"updatedAt":finalid}},//change as needed
      {
       sort: {_id:-1},
      }
  );
```

I haven't tested it out on anything but the most recent version of Node.js but I hope it helps.